Encountering an ERR_BAD_REQUEST error when trying to use the Outlook Calendar API
I have created an application in app registration in Azure admin exchange, and i am trying to use the Outlook APIs, using the clinetid, tenant id and secret key, But i am getting ERR_BAD_REQUEST error for https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events. I have added Calendars.Read, Calendars.ReadWrite and Calendars.ReadWrit.Shared

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
